# TypeError: this.getWindow(...).$ is undefined

Tags: jquery, ajax, angularjs, ckeditor, modalviewcontroller

I get

> TypeError: this.getWindow(...).$ is undefined

When I used `CKEDITOR.instances['pageContent'].getData();` for saving record to database using `ajax`. I am using `Modal`.

Please tell me how can I solve this error.

```
<div class="modal-body">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label>Page Content</label>
        <textarea id="pageContent" name="pageContent" ng-model="editCmsPageDetail.pageContent" class="form-control ckeditor">
        </textarea>
    </div>
</div>
```

This is my textarea having id `pageContent`.
Script as below:

```
<script>
      //CKEDITOR.replace('pageContent');
      $('#pageContent').ckeditor();
</script>
```

**Function on click of ok button**

```
$scope.ok = function () {       
    $scope.editCmsPageDetail['pageContent'] = CKEDITOR.instances['pageContent'].getData();
    //alert(pageContent);

    var getCmsPageUpdateUrl = $('#updateCmsPageUrl').val();

    var httpRequest = $http({
        method: 'POST',
        url: getCmsPageUpdateUrl,
        data : $scope.editCmsPageDetail
    }).success(function(data, status) {

        if(data.response.error) {

        } else if(data.response.cmsPageDetail) {

        }
    });

    $modalInstance.dismiss($scope.editCmsPageDetail);
};
```

Comment: `$('#pageContent').ckeditor();` this can be wrapped within doc ready block, not sure but might help.

Comment: provide a fiddle if possible

Comment: You are using a bootstrap modal?

Comment: Yes,  bootstrap modal.

Comment: $('#pageContent').ckeditor(); It create more error...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably you are missing the jQuery adapter for CKEditor, see: http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/guide/dev_jquery

Alternatively you can start it by set `ckeditor` class on the `textarea`, like you are doing now, see: http://ckeditor.com/ckeditor_4.3_beta/samples/replacebyclass.html

Then you can access the ckeditor instance and get its value, like:

```
$(document).on('click', '#AddBrandButton', function () {
    alert(CKEDITOR.instances['pageContent'].getData());
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/IrvinDominin/9p8pkcpc/

Comment: I am already using  jQuery adapter for CKEditor and implemented ckeditor class.

Comment: I am tried your solution. till alert everything is ok. but when I take this content in variable and pass it into json like, It gives error... #pagecontent I received, It is in Html coding...

Comment: like `$scope.editCmsPageDetail['pageContent'] = CKEDITOR.instances['pageContent'].getData();`

Comment: @Choldas the HTML encoded is correct because the plugin use HTML for WYSIWYG